# Finding number of elements $n\in\{1,2,...,20\}$ for which $1.9\le\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}\le2$ where $A_n=\max\left\{\binom{n}{r}:0\le r\le n\right\}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

**Q.For each positive no. $n$
$$A_n=\max\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ r\end{array}\right):0\leq r\leq n\right\}$$Then the no. of elements of $n$ in ${1,2,3.............20}$ for which $1.9\leq\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}\leq2$ is__?**

Attempt:

> $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}\left(\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}\right)=0$$ to calculate the maximum $r$ for a particular $n$.I do not know how to calculate this.

**How to perform this derivation?**

Another Attempt:

> I plotted the graph of $$\frac{n!}{(n-x)!x!}$$ for any particular $n$.
>
> On inspection,I found that the function reaches maximum value at $x=n/2$[image]
>
> $$A_n=\frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!\frac{n}{2})!}$$
>
> $$A_{n-1}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(\frac{n-1}{2})!\frac{n-1}{2})!}$$
>
> Therefore,$$1.9\leq\frac{\frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!\frac{n}{2})!}}{\frac{(n-1)!}{(\frac{n-1}{2})!\frac{n-1}{2})!}}\leq2$$

Now I am stuck again.**Can I proceed from here and how?**

If none of this attempts are useful,**how to solve this question?**

Comment: The derivative makes no sense for integers. It is better to compute the ratio (r, n)/ (r+1,n)

Comment: The problem can be reduced to find $\min\{(n-r)!r!:r\in\{0,\ldots,n\}\}$

Comment: Simplify that big fraction (remember the definition of the factorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: observe that $(n-r)!r!=s!(n-s)!$ for all $(n,s)$ such that $r=n-s$.

Then $$\{(n-r)!r!:r\in\{0,\ldots,n\}\}=\{(n-r)!r!:r\in\{0,\ldots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\}\}$$

where $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) on $n/2$. Now verify that the function

$$f:\{0,\ldots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\}\to \Bbb N,\quad r\mapsto (n-r)!r!$$

is strictly decreasing, i.e. $f(k)>f(k+1),\forall k\in\{0,\ldots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\}$. Then

$$f^{-1}(\min\{(n-r)!r!:r\in\{0,\ldots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\}\})=\lfloor n/2\rfloor\implies A_n=\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$$

Then the question about the desired evaluation becomes

$$\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}=\frac{\frac{n!}{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor!\cdot\lfloor n/2\rfloor!}}{\frac{(n-1)!}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor!\cdot\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor!}}=\frac{n}{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}$$

In the last step I used the fact that $\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor+\lfloor n/2\rfloor=n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$, what implies that $\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor -\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor=1$.

Comment: Could you please show the the calculations behind the last step?

Comment: Yes, the last step is a bit ugly. I will edit.